# Trying to make Conway's game of life, how do I get the rect to fit into a grid square in pygame

Tags: matrix, pygame, conways-game-of-life

```
import pygame, copy,random

w,h = 500,500
cellsize=5
cells=[]
pygame.init()

width, height = w/cellsize, h/cellsize

width = int(width)
height=int(height)

dis= pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
dis.fill((0,0,0))

randomBool=[]

cellPc=0.001
count = totalcount = 0
for y in range(h):
  randomBool.append([])
  for x in range(w):
    if random.random() < cellPc:
      randomBool[y].append(True)
      count += 1
    else:
      randomBool[y].append(False)
    totalcount +=1
#sojipo ajs;koojihhasuiio h;asjioasddfoiaidhoiiosaiof


running=True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
      quit()
  for x in range(0, w, cellsize):
    pygame.draw.line(dis,(123,123,123),(x,0),(x,h))
  for y in range(0, h, cellsize):
    pygame.draw.line(dis,(123,123,123),(0,y),(w,y))
  pygame.display.update()
  for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
      if randomBool[y][x]==True:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis,(255,0,0),(x,y,cellsize,cellsize))
```

I thought it would just fit in the grid but the matrix wont work. I'm semi-new to the idea of matrices in python, so I'm mostly out of my league here. How exactly can I make them fit on the grid. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It may not be a matrix but I think it is. I just want to know how to fit it (the rects) inside the grid

Answer (score 1):

Use the `//` (floor division) operator to calculate the number of rows and columns:

<s>`width, height = w/cellsize, h/cellsize`</s>

```py
width, height = w // cellsize, h // cellsize
```

The number of columns and rows of the grid is `width` x `height` and not `w` x `h`. The top left position of a cell is `(col * cellsize, row * cellsize)`:

```py
for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        if randomBool[row][col]==True:
            x, y = col * cellsize, row * cellsize
            pygame.draw.rect(dis, (255,0,0), (x, y, cellsize, cellsize))
```